# JQuery stop element from fading back in

Tags: javascript, jquery, fade

I've made this little snippet to scroll the window to the top of the page.

```
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        $("#scrollup").fadeIn("slow");
    }); 
    $("#scrollup").click(function(){
        $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'normal', function() {
            $("#scrollup").fadeOut("slow");
        });
    });
```

However, when the scrollup div fades out after the window scrolls, it fades back in. How do I stop this from happening? Thanks.

---

I think I have found a reasonable solution

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
        $('.scrollup').fadeIn();
    } else {
        $('.scrollup').fadeOut();
    }
});
```

Would this be easier than changing my original code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out `.stop()`: http://api.jquery.com/stop/

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
        $('.scrollup').stop().fadeIn();
    } else {
        $('.scrollup').stop().fadeOut();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this is basically what I'm now using, what is the advantage of  stop() though?

Answer (score 1):

You should make sure that the scrollup div isn't faded in when you are at the top or when it is already faded in ( visible )

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if ( $(window).scrollTop() !== 0 or $("#scrollup").is(":hidden") ) then {
         $("#scrollup").fadeIn("slow");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just add an if statement to check if it is at the top:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if($("body").scrollTop()!=0)
        $("#scrollup").fadeIn("slow");
    }); 
    $("#scrollup").click(function(){
        $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'normal', function() {
            $("#scrollup").fadeOut("slow");
        });
    });​
```